# Question: grouping settings together

Tags: iphone, settings

I'm developing a number of application which have a Settings pane, 
following the AppPrefs sample by Apple.

Within the Settings application, my settings appear in the same 
"group" with other applications.

Anyone know of a way to do one of the following:

1. Group all my application settings (e.g. App1 and App2) grouped 
   under one prompt (e.g. "Rubale >" then opening to a new tab with "App1 >" and "App2 >" - like "General >" leads to "Keyboard >" and "International >")
2. Have all myapplication settings grouped (like the Settings groups 
   the Apple apps separately from my apps today).

I know this is doable, since on my iPhone I see "CyDelete and Lock 
Calendar" grouped on their own, and "iKeyEx" on its own, and "Skype" 
and my own apps in yet another group...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no official way. You'll note that the only non-Apple applications that are able to do it are only for jail-broken handsets.